# Change date on select (jquery.datepick)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to know how I can change the date in my "selectedDate"  with jquery datepick. Here's my HTML where I want the magic to show

```
<h3>Historique des tâches (<span class="selectedDate"><?= date("Y-m-d");?></span>) <span class="chooseDate">Choisir date</span> <span class="taskDate"></span></h3>
```

And the javascript

```
$(".chooseDate").toggle(function() {
    $(this).text("Choisir date");
    $(".taskDate").datepick({
        onSelect: function(date) {
          alert($.datepick.formatDate(date))
        }
      }); 
}, 
function() {
  $(this).text("Choisir date");
    $(".taskDate").datepick('destroy'); 
});
```

When I select a date it should popup an alert message with the selected date in yyyy-mm-dd format but nothing happens.

Could someone help me?

Thanks

Update (Found it):

```
$(".taskDate").datepick({
      onSelect: function(test){
        var newDate = new Date(test);
        alert(newDate.getFullYear()+'-'+(newDate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+newDate.getDate());
      }
    });
```

I've just reformat the date it gave me to the one I wanted. Event by telling it the show it in yyyy-mm-dd format it was still showing me the full date with day , time zone, etc...

Thanks guys

Comment: First check the html code from the browser (view page source). All things be fine? Then take a view to the error console from browser (except IE, all famous browser has got one). Is there an error message?

Comment: No error in the firebug console :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".taskDate").datepick({
        onSelect: function(date) {
          alert($.datepick.formatDate(date))
        }
      }).bind('dateSelected', function(e, selectedDate, $td) {
                alert(selectedDate);
        });
```

OK, then try this:

```
    $('.taskDate').datepicker({ onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { alert("Your alert"); } });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should provide a format to the formatDate function, according to the [jQuery DatePicker documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker)

```
$.datepicker.formatDate( format, date, settings )
```

Also, shouldn't your

```
$.datepick
```

be

```
$.datepicker
```

?

Comment: @Warface Sorry, I thought it was the jQuery built-in datapicker. But also if you have a look at the sample codes on that side, you see that you still have to specify the date format for that function like so: $.datepick.formatDate('dd/mm/yyyy', $('.taskDate').datepick('getDate')[0])